# Jenkins : Email Notification : Latest build status URL in the mail body

Tags: email, jenkins

I use Jenkins extended email notification plugin to get an email after a build finishes...
and when i get the mail i see URL which gives the latest changes done to the build for ex:something like: <://abcd.l%20Automation%20-%20IE8%20Browser/changes>...

Instead of this i would like to see the URL in the mail which directly gives the build status
for ex: some thing like://abcd.l%20Automation%20-%20IE8%20Browser/buildnumber>...so that clicking on this URL should directly open the build status page....

is there any way we can configure with the jenkins ?

I have default content being set as below  : $PROJECT_NAME - Build # $BUILD_NUMBER - $BUILD_STATUS:

Check console output at $BUILD_URL to view the results.

please let me know ...
musaffir

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the "build status page", as opposed to the build page which is referenced by $BUILD_URL ?

Comment: Hi ,Exactly thats what I meant... a build URL...

Comment: i do have this in the default content set up at jenkins :Check console output at $BUILD_URL to view the results....but i dont get the build URL in the mail....instead i get the build changes URL

Comment: The build changes are shown in the $BUILD_URL, along with other top level info like test results.  Can you post an example of the URL you're looking for ?  You can remove the hostname part.

Answer (score 1):

$BUILD_URL should work.

Please check "Advanced Settings" of "Editable Email Notification" plugin in your job. You might have overridden the default settings of "Failure" trigger